# "SELECT ... WHERE ... IN" with unknown number of parameters

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm attempting to perform a query in the form of...

```
SELECT col2 FROM tab WHERE col1 IN (val1, val2, val3...)
```

...where the values are stored in a Python list/tuple of arbitrary length. I can't seem to find a "clean" way to do it.

```
>>> db = connect(":memory:")
>>> db.execute("CREATE TABLE tab (col1 INTEGER, col2 TEXT)")
>>> db.execute("INSERT INTO tab VALUES(1,'one')")
>>> db.execute("INSERT INTO tab VALUES(2,'two')")
>>> db.execute("INSERT INTO tab VALUES(3,'three')")
>>> db.execute("INSERT INTO tab VALUES(4,'four')")
>>> db.execute("INSERT INTO tab VALUES(5,'five')")
>>> db.commit()

# Expected result
>>> db.execute("SELECT col2 FROM tab WHERE col1 IN (1,3,4)").fetchall()
[(u'one',), (u'three',), (u'four',)]

>>> vals = (1,3,4)

>>> db.execute("SELECT col2 FROM tab WHERE col1 IN (?)", vals).fetchall()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.

>>> db.execute("SELECT col2 FROM tab WHERE col1 IN (?)", (vals,)).fetchall()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

>>> db.execute("SELECT col2 FROM tab WHERE col1 IN (?)", (','.join(str(val) for val in vals),)).fetchall()
[]

>>>
```

Now I can do the following, which (I think... please correct me if I'm wrong) retains the security of the built-in parameter substitution, but it's still a bit ugly:

```
>>> db.execute("SELECT col2 FROM tab WHERE col1 IN (" + ",".join("?"*len(vals)) + ")", vals).fetchall()
[(u'one',), (u'three',), (u'four',)]
>>>
```

Is that my best option, or is there a nicer way around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite: bind list of values to "WHERE col IN ( :PRM )"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788724/sqlite-bind-list-of-values-to-where-col-in-prm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's your best option *without using additional libraries*. I certainly have [advocated just that technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142554/sqlite3-python-executemany-select/14142611#14142611) in the past, [more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245396/using-a-where-in-statement/14245421#14245421) in fact.

You could also switch to using SQLAlchemy, which generates SQL for you, but that requires you to climb its learning curve and rewrite most of your application.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks. This was a hard one to search for because the important terms are such common words...

Answer (score 1):

A simple and clean solution is:

```
vals = [1,3,4]
cursor.execute('SELECT col2 FROM tab WHERE col1 IN {}'.format(str(tuple(vals))
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was trying to avoid... plugging the variables directly into the query string (rather than using parameter substitution) leaves you open to potential SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I agree, but it seems there is still no safe solution for that!

Comment: The solution I used (the last example in the question) is ugly, but does still maintain proper parameter substitution.