# Python SQLite SELECT LIKE IN [list]

Tags: python, sqlite

How to write SQL query in Python to select elements LIKE IN Python list?

For example, I have Python list of strings

```
Names=['name_1','name_2',..., 'name_n']
```

and SQLite_table.

My task is to find shortest way to

```
SELECT elements FROM SQLite_table WHERE element_name LIKE '%name_1%'
SELECT elements FROM SQLite_table WHERE element_name LIKE '%name_2%'
...
SELECT elements FROM SQLite_table WHERE element_name LIKE '%name_n%'
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15041534/2266261 ?

Comment: No. The problem is LIKE.

Comment: `SELECT elements FROM SQLite_table WHERE element_name LIKE '%name_1%' OR element_name LIKE '%name_2%' OR element_name LIKE '%name_n%'` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need a regular expression of the form `name_1|name_2|name_3|…`, which you can generate using `'|'.join(Names)`:

```
SELECT elements FROM SQLite_table WHERE element_name REGEXP 'name_1|name_2|name_3|…|name_n'
```

Check [How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601) for instructions on how to use regular expressions in SQLite.

Comment: There is no REGEX operator, and the linked answers say that REGEXP is not available by default.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. However, the linked answers give enough information to install and use the `REGEXP` operator. For example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365451) installs the operator in 5 lines of Python.

Answer (score 3):

Mmhh

```
Names=['name_1','name_2','name_n']
for i in Names:
    sql = "SELECT elements FROM SQLite_table WHERE element_name LIKE '%" + i + "%'" 
    print sql

SELECT elements FROM SQLite_table WHERE element_name LIKE '%name_1%'
SELECT elements FROM SQLite_table WHERE element_name LIKE '%name_2%'
SELECT elements FROM SQLite_table WHERE element_name LIKE '%name_n%'
```