# How to perform LIKE query in Sqlite with a List of query String

Tags: java, sqlite, android-room

I have a sqlite table with following columns

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_one
```

```java
+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  ID  |   name   |                         dates                          |
+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 1001 | SINGLE   | [{"dayOfMonth":5,"month":9}]                           | 
| 1002 | MULTIPLE | [{"dayOfMonth":2,"month":9},{"dayOfMonth":3,"month":9} |
+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now if I query either one of below return correct info:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE dates LIKE '%dayOfMonth":3%' 
SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE dates LIKE '%dayOfMonth":5%'
```

But I want to combine this two statement in one single line. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940332/python-sqlite-select-like-in-list) answer but didn't worked for me.

Here dates is a variable length and not exact. The `IN` operation is also not working.
I want to perform this operation `List<Item> getAllOf(List<String> queryStrings)` which will return me a list of all matched item. What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to combine this two statement in one single line.

Why you just don't use OR operator between LIKE conditions ? :)

I mean

```
SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE dates LIKE '%dayOfMonth":3%' OR dates LIKE '%dayOfMonth":5%'
```

General rule here: don't use REGEXP in WHERE conditions if you don't have to. With regexp you lose INDEX search advantage..

Comment: Yes I can use this method but my query string list may contain more than 100 items. Is there any other efficient way?

Comment: talking about performance regexp is not better then OR operator. Even OR LIKE is much faster if you have INDEX on `dates` column and if you do prefix search `LIKE 'dayOfMonth":3%'`. If you use regexp then INDEX is not used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do this with `LIKE`, you need to repeat the conditions, using `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_one 
WHERE dates LIKE '%dayOfMonth":3%' OR dates LIKE '%dayOfMonth":5%'
```

A regex solution would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE dates REGEXP 'dayOfMonth":[35]'
```

`[35]` is a character class, meaning that any of the two characters must be found.

A more generic approach if you have more than one character is to use `|` (which basically stands for "or" in regexes):

```
SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE dates REGEXP 'dayOfMonth":(3)|(5)'
```

You can put as many characters as you want within the parentheses

Comment: `REGEXP` shows error. `There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: REGEXP)`