# Using sqlite3 DB-API multiple parameter substitution in SELECT statements

Tags: python, sqlite

Given:

```
letters = list("abc")
```

I'd like to get all rows in `characters` that contain any of the letters in `letters` in their `c` column. I can do this, but only with python's string operations, which isn't suitable given it's vulnerabilities.

Ideally (my example is simplified) this would be using the GLOB clause.

E.g.

```
>>> cur.execute(**the statement here**)
>>> print(cur.fetchall())
>>> [('a',), ('b',), ('c',)]
```

Creation of the db:

```
import sqlite3
import string

def char_generator():
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        yield (c,)

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table characters(c)")

cur.executemany("insert into characters(c) values (?)", char_generator())
```

Comment: I don't think it's quite a dupe, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041534/select-where-in-with-unknown-number-of-parameters) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this sample can help you.

```
import sqlite3
import string

def char_generator():
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        yield (c,)


con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

def initdb():
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("create table characters(c)")

    cur.executemany("insert into characters(c) values (?)", char_generator())

def search(value):
    values = [c for c in value]
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM characters WHERE c IN ({0})'.format(','.join(['?' for c in values])), values)
    return cur.fetchall()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    initdb()
    print(search("abcde"))
```

This code uses parameters. So you do not need to worry about SQL Injection.