# python SQLite selection by array of values

Tags: python, sqlite

There is the executemany and some other methods I have found for inserting data.  However execute many doesn't work for SELECT.

In the sql format, the IN and VALUES can be used, for example:

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM Table1 WHERE col3 IN (VALUES (1),(2),(3) )
```

How can I perform this operation in python with an array?

Here was an attempt, but has an issue binding:

```
dataArr = (1,2,3)
c.execute( "SELECT col1,col2 FROM Table1 WHERE col3 IN (?) ",(dataArr,) )
ret = c.fetchall()
```

I have also tried the string contcatenation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142554/sqlite3-python-executemany-select) but it flattens the rows into a single array.  The benefit is that it performs 2~3x faster than a loop for me, which is the main concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this :

```
args=['1','2','3']

sql="select col1,col2 FROM Table1 WHERE col3 IN in ({seq})".format(seq=','.join(['?']*len(args)))

rows=cur.execute(sql, args)

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the best i could ever find.